# Remove word after match

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

Consider the following line of text (taken from a MySQL insert):

```
"description" varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

I want to return

```
"description" varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

I.e. I want to remove `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`. However, the collation following the `COLLATE` keyword can vary depending on the original Database schema.

I've come across lookaheads, but not quite sure how I could use it to remove the word.

Comment: `awk '/COLLATE/ {$3=$4=""}1' file`...

Comment: That outputs the word following the match, how would I then remove it?

Comment: It removes both `COLLATE` and the field immediately after it; isn't that what you were after?

Comment: Apologies, yes that worked. Feel free to write your solution as an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the field after `COLLATE` contains no whitespace, you can use a simple Awk one-liner:

```
 awk '/COLLATE/ {$3=$4=""}1' file
```

This matches on the pattern `COLLATE` and then prints the entire file without the third and fourth field on the matching record (line).